# Can Qt inject dynamically generated content into loaded help collections?

Tags: qt, qt5, qthelp

**Background**: I have a Qt application that dynamically loads modules at run-time. These modules supply their own documentation as normal null-terminated `char *` utf-8 blobs that I can access from the Qt application.

I want to present these documentation blobs to the user using the Qt Help Framework; that is, I want to somehow inject each module's documentation as it's own section along side the main documentation so that users have one single logical reference to to refer to.

When I went to implement this in Qt, I found that `QHelpEngine` expects precompiled help collection files (`.qhc`). I couldn't find API to add documentation to a collection once loaded.

I should note that I'm aware of both `QTextBrowser` or `QWebView`. The issue with using these instead of `QHelpEngine` is that I'd have to give up or reimplement all the features that the `QHelpEngine` provides (indexing, organization, formatting, ..etc). I don't want to do either if I can help it.

**Question**: Is it possible to inject dynamically generated help content into a loaded help collection at run-time? If not, is there a preferred workaround that leads to a consistent help browsing experience for the user?